# Limb darkening coefficients for BRITE and Johnson:V passbands

Tags: binary-star, raw-data, eclipsing-star-systems

Where to find limb darkening coefficients for BRITE and Johnson:V passbands, please? Do any tables exist or are there any relations for their guest? Many thanks